ASP.NET Web API 2 - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel
Every other answer to "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" essentially says "make sure TLS 1.2 is on". This has not worked, and I have the Wireshark captures to back it up.
Now, I have a .NET Framework 4.7.2 ASP.NET Web API running in IIS. I am trying to interact with a 3rd-party API that requires a client certificate for mTLS. When my api sends the initial login request, I get the error The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. The exception does not seem to contain any details about cause and does not have an inner exception.
The crazy part is, I only get this error when my API is running in IIS on a Windows 2022 server (AWS EC2). I do not get the error when I test locally. Furthermore, I do not get the error when I copy the exact code from my API into a console app and run that on the same server that the API runs on.
The certificate is loaded like so:
using (var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client())
{
    var response = s3Client.GetObject(bucket, key);

    using (response.ResponseStream)
    using (var file = new MemoryStream())
    {
        response.ResponseStream.CopyTo(file);
        cert = new X509Certificate2(file.ToArray(), certPassword);
    }
}

and used like so:
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
httpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

_httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler)
{
    BaseAddress = _config.BaseUri
};

In Wireshark, it seems like the conversation just cuts off.
Here is what success looks like (console app):
Success
Here is what failure looks like (ASP.NET Web API 2)
Failure
From answers to similar questions, I have tried:

adding every registry entry related to enabling TLSv1.2 on Windows.
adding ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.tls12 to the code.
adding ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true to the code.
making sure that httpRuntime is set to 4.7.2 in the Web.config.

Nothing made any difference and Wireshark shows TLSv1.2 is happening.

Please show the full exception message, including any $exception.InnerException as that contains more details.

Don't set ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol it's not necessary and in fact counter-productive on newer versions of .NET after 4.6. By the looks of the Wireshark trace, the server is requesting you to provide a Client Certificate and it's not providing it. Is the certificate private key accessible to the IIS App Pool user? See eg https://docs.pega.com/bundle/robotic-automation-221/page/robotic-automation/sync-server-status/provide-iis-read-access-to-certificate.html

@Charlieface unfortunately there is no inner exception. The certificate is loaded into memory from S3 rather than from the file system. I updated the post to show that code.

Review the application pool identity and make sure that has access to the certificate in the remote server. Not for file system loading, but for local user certificate access allowed.

You might need to add X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable to the constructor of X509Certificate2

@Sieg Seems to be using a certificate created from bytes

@Charlieface is read it as bytes but from an s3, then it already exist with permissions and keys. When the certificate is generated is required to ensure that the users are included in the generation. I'm I right?

If the private key is cached on the server (eg you imported the PFX into them achine store) then that can sometimes cause issues, as Windows might connect the in-memory certificate with the private key which has different permissions.
